# Different .NET 4.5 in windows 7 & 8?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, windows-8.1

I have written a .NET 4.5 app on a windows 7 machine with Visual Studio 2012, and it installs and runs fine on windows 7.

When I try to deploy it on a windows 8 machine, it crashes pretty catastrophically, with not very useful output in the event viewer.
A trace with *Dependency walker* suggests it couldn't find a method in one/some of the core windows dlls.
For example:

```
LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned 0x00007FFDEA780000.  
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFDEA780000 [MSCOREEI.DLL], "RegisterShimImplCallback") called from "MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFDEA82F3A9 and returned 0x00007FFDEA783444.  
GetProcAddress(0x00007FFDEA780000 [MSCOREEI.DLL], "RegisterShimImplCleanupCallback") called from "MSCOREE.DLL" at address 0x00007FFDEA82F3BC and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).
```

When examining mscoreei.dll, I notice:

**Windows 7 machine**
v4.0.30319.18408
613,456 bytes

**Windows 8 machine**
v4.0.30319.33440
633,424 bytes

Both machines (according to [ASoft .NET version detector](http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html)) have .NET 4.5 Full.

Why do my machines have different builds of .NET, and how can I ensure the compiler on my windows 7 machine targets the correct version that windows 8 machines have?

Comment: At a guess - service packs/security patches. Run Windows update, perhaps?

Comment: @Bridge: I've run windows update a million times on both.

Comment: I see you've tagged Windows 8.1, which comes with .net 4.5.1, but are using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 which comes with .net 4.5.0, which is why the version number is different. No idea why it would fail catastrophically though!

Comment: @JMK: I have installed 4.5.1 on my windows 7 machine in case that was the issue..

Comment: Weird, [it looks like LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a81867d9-c655-4f14-a6aa-761a0d985cab/loadlibraryexw-and-loadwithalteredsearchpath-question) is deprecated on Windows 7, maybe it doesn't exist on Windows 8.1 at all?

Comment: @JMK: Good spotting. I downloaded the [4.5.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229516) and targeted that in case that was the issue.. But no change at all..

Comment: Are you using LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH anywhere in your code to load up C++ DLL's, or anything similar?

Comment: @JMK: Not me - but possibly a third-party dll?

Comment: I added an answer, just summing up what I put in the comments mainly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is entirely normal.  Windows 8 also has a custom version of .NET 3.5.  Nothing unusual, the .NET Framework does have a heavy dependency on the operating system version.  And the reason it comes pre-installed on Windows 8.

That dependency is particularly noteworthy for MSCoree, the "loader shim" for the .NET framework.  It pulls a pretty dramatic stunt, it can get Windows to create a 64-bit process from a 32-bit EXE file.  Nothing simple about that, it closely co-operates with the loader in Windows to make that happen, patching internal data structures to get it to create a 64-bit process.

Seeing the "The specified procedure could not be found" error is also nothing unusual.  This is why it uses GetProcAddress() instead of having an implicit import dependency.  Using GetProcAddress() is a very common technique to find out if a particular api function is in fact supported.

I seriously doubt you found the real reason your program is crashing yet.  Never forget to implement the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event to report unhandled exceptions, the crash info you get from Windows is quite useless.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, either somewhere in your code or in a third party DLL, the LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH value is being used.

This is because the [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) function is being called somewhere. This imports **kernel32.dll** [which is different in Windows 7 compared to Windows 8](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/dump/win7_vs_win8/export%20lists/kernel32.dll.html).

LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH which is mentioned in the error [was already deprecated in Windows 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a81867d9-c655-4f14-a6aa-761a0d985cab/loadlibraryexw-and-loadwithalteredsearchpath-question), it could be that this doesn't exist in Windows 8 at all.

I think you need to install Visual Studio on Windows 8.1, and debug your code from there until you hit an exception. It will probably help you pinpoint where the problem is faster than compiling on 7 and trying to run on 8 while trying to decipher cryptic error messages. Once you find the problem library, you could contact the vendor to see if they have an updated version.

Comment: Good advice to try debugging on 8.1. Unfortunately, it compiles and runs perfectly with exactly the same project file and source...

Comment: No errors at all. No Problems. The code is the same (it is compiled by the 8.1 machine _on_ the 7 machine hard drive). The project is now targeting .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly helpful answer - but it was a third-party dll that couldn't handle being run in a x64 process on Win 8.
No more information on what exactly caused the actual issue